# How can I find our FAA airport designation number?

Tags: runways

Several years ago we were issued an airport designation number by the FAA. The information was lost when my father died. How do I find out what our designation number is?

Comment: Runways are numbered according to [magnetic heading](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/65/how-are-runways-numbered).  I'm not aware of other designation numbers.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "runway designation number"? And which airport are you talking about, i.e. what's the airport code?

Comment: Do you mean airport identifier rather than runway designation?  If you can give the location of the runway (lat/lon, reference to a city, name, etc) we might be able to find it.

Comment: @Pondlife I think the airport code is exactly what he's looking for.

Answer (score 13):

What you're looking for is the FAA [Airport/Facility Directory (A/FD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airport/Facility_Directory). You can search it on the [FAA A/FD Advanced search page](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/dafd/search/advanced/). If your runway is registered as an airport with the FAA, its airport identifier will be in the A/FD. It will also include the runway numbers (there will be one for each end of the runway,) as well as other information about the runway (surface type, exact heading, altitude, etc.) See [How are runways numbered?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/65/755) for more information on runway numbers. Another website available for searching A/FD information is [airnav.com](http://www.airnav.com/airports/).

Another way to find information on the airport is to look at a [Sectional Chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sectional_chart). For most private airports, an 'R' with a circle around it will appear where your runway is located and it will have the name of the airport beside it. You can then use that name to look it up in the A/FD. [Skyvector.com](https://skyvector.com/) is an easy way to look at sectional charts. It works a lot like Google Maps, except that it shows you the FAA sectional chart for your area rather than a normal map. You can just zoom in on your area to find the airport marker.

Your airport will look something like the one that I've circled in red on this sectional chart image:

[image: Sectional chart showing private airport]

If your runway has a hard surface (i.e. it's paved with asphalt or concrete) and is more than 1,500 feet long, it might look like the airport circled in the picture below rather than having the circled 'R'. In this picture, the purple circle indicates the airport and the white line within the circle indicates the location and orientation of the runway.

[image: Sectional chart showing private airport with paved runway]

Answer (score 2):

Search [directly on the FAA page](http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/dafd/search/).