# What would be the designation for 4 parallel runways?

Tags: runways

If an airport were to have 4 parallel runways (ex if KSEA added another one), what would the designations be. Would it be 34L, CL, CR, and L? I know in Orlando they are separated by the terminals, and thus quite far apart, and they're numbered 17 and 17 and 18, for example. But if they were right next to each other, would that make a difference? Would the two-number system still be used there?

Comment: I disagree with the close votes. The previous question is a very general numbering question and does nothing to get an answer for this question on a specific case.

Comment: @Robert [Yes it does](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/8071/64). This question is in fact explicitly answered there.

Comment: @voretaq7 I missed that part, apologies. Easily missed with so many long answers.

Comment: @Robert Yup, it's easy to miss - that's why I linked to it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Airports can have a left, center and right runways.  Memphis (KMEM) is a good example.  Airports with four or more parallel runways are left and right with the numbers off by one.  Los Angeles (KLAX) and Chicago (KORD) are good examples of such an arrangement.

Comment: Roissy Charles-de-Gaulle (LFPG) also uses the same strategy in Paris, with runways 9L/9R/8L/8R

Comment: [KATL](https://flightaware.com/resources/airport/KATL/APD/AIRPORT+DIAGRAM) has six parallel runways

Comment: @TomMcW where? I only see 5.

Comment: @lightbord Sorry, you're right. There's only 5. I was thinking it was 6

Comment: The 6th one is a little further south. It's only used by the unicorns, though, so it's not on most charts.  :)