# What is ILS 114 / 162 / 294?

Tags: airport, ils, airport-markings

I am searching for airports that have ILS (not sure if there is a "law" that any airport servicing civil flights must have one).

So I googled around and found this nice site http://www.azworldairports.com.

So I've been looking at airport in [Vienna](http://www.azworldairports.com/airports/a1080vie.cfm) and in airfield section there is following:

> **Runway 1**: Heading 11/29, 3 500m (11 482ft), 75, ICAO Cat. I, 3B, Aircraft size max: E, Rwy 11, **ILS 114**, Lighting: 11 CAT 1/PAPI, No Restrictions, Rwy 29, **ILS 294**, Lighting: 29 CAT 1/PAPI, No Restrictions
>
> **Runway 2**: Heading 16/34, 3 600m (11 811ft), 75, ICAO Cat. I, 3B, Aircraft size max: E, **ILS 162**, Lighting: CAT III B/PAPI, No Restrictions

What exactly is ILS 114 / 162 / 294?

Comment: "Not sure if there is a law that any airport servicing civil flights must have one." Oh no, that is certainly not the case.

Comment: @J.Hougaard Indeed. The vast majority don't have it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's the ILS heading to the runway.

Based on [how runways are numbered](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/65/how-are-runways-numbered), runway 11's heading will be somewhere between 105° and 114°, 114 nails it down.

Comment: Great, how do I know which category the ILS is?

Comment: @Kyslik It'll be stated on the approach plate, examples [here](http://www.vacc-austria.org/index.php?page=content/chartlist&icao=loww&language=en).

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the link.